# Expecting class path separator ';' before '\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\lib\shrinkedAndroid.jar' in argument number 8

Tags: android, xamarin

Using VS 2015 for Xamarin development, when I attempt to build an Android project which has Enable Multi-Dex checked, I get the following error :-

> Expecting class path separator ';' before
>   '\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\lib\shrinkedAndroid.jar' in
>   argument number 8

Any idea why this might be happening and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If your path to SDK location contains space, the build process will cause this issue.

> Eg : If SDK Location is `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk, it has
>   space between **Program** **Files**.

If your SDK is in `Program Files` renaming it by removing the space won't be feasible. So copy the SDK folder to some other location say `C:\Android\` & set the Android SDK Path in Visual Studio to the new Location.

**To change Android SDK location in Visual Studio, Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings->Android SDK Location (Change)**

Comment: Why is Microsoft's installer installing it by default to a folder which will cause it  not to work?

Comment: @as9876 because it does work until someone or something changes stuff and after updating things, stuff does not work anymore. Just have headache after headache with Xamarin... looks like it will never stop